# Solving an optimisation problem with a 1D array, 1 constraint, and 1 optimisation criterion

Tags: python

What would be the best approach (method/function) to solve the following problem?

I have a (8760,1) array "Power", which is a time series of the machine operating power during a year with a 1 hour resolution. Each value fluctuates within a certain predefined range of 1:500 (maximum machine power).

Using values from this array and other static data at hand I create additional arrays. Using these arrays I calculate a constraint value of X (total production volume of the machine). Finally I end up with a result value of Z (production cost).

So I have 8760 elements, each of these can have a 1:500 value. By varying the Power array values, I would like to find lowest and highest possible values of Z (production cost), while keeping X (total production volume of the machine) constant.

**Edit. Source code added**

```
machine_power_kW=500
electricity_cost_Eur_kW=0.10
time_resolution_hours=1

file_name_1='**.csv'
with open(file_name_1, 'r') as f:
    next(csv.reader(f))
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
power_array=np.array(data[:-1], dtype=float)
file_name_2='**.csv'
with open(file_name_2, 'r') as f:
    next(csv.reader(f))
    data = list(csv.reader(f))

Consumption_lookup_table=np.array(data, dtype=float)  # a lookup table with energy consumption for different power values (in %)
Consumption_for_power_array=np.empty([len(power_array),1])

#create Consumption_for_power_array
for i in range(len(power_array)):
    p=round(power_array.item(i)/machine_power_kW,2)
    if p>=0.15:
        pos=int(p*100 - 15)  #no production with load under 15%
        Consumption_for_power_array[i]=Consumption_lookup_table[pos]
    else:
        Consumption_for_power_array[i]=1e9999999

#calculate amount of items produced
items_produced=power_array/Consumption_for_power_array
items_produced=time_resolution_hours*items_produced.sum()

#calculate price of 1 item produced
opex=time_resolution_hours*(power_array.sum()*electricity_cost_Eur_kW)   #cost of consumed electricity
cost_of_item=opex/items_produced
print(cost_of_item)
```

I would like to vary 8760 values of power_array in a range of 0:500 to see max and min of cost_of_item, while Consumption_for_power_array is changing after the power_array.

Comment: Less words, more code please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to solve an optimization problem. There are many Python packages that can help define your problem and solve it using an Open-source or Paid solver. I recommend using [Pulp](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/), if you're trying to solve a linear optimization problem (meaning you don't have any variable multiplication in your formulation).

To install [Pulp](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/) execute the following command:

```
$ pip install pulp
```

### Example Problem

Since you didn't specify your actual problem equations, nor gave an example of how your "static data" you'll have to make some the modifications the example below:

```py
import numpy as np
import pulp as plp

# == Generate Some random data for the example ========================
SIZE = 8760
power = np.random.randint(1, 5001, size=SIZE)
unit_production_volume = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=SIZE)
X = (unit_production_volume * power)
total_production_volume = X.sum()
unit_cost_power = np.random.random(SIZE)

z = (X * unit_cost_power)
total_cost = z.sum()

# == Define and solve the first optimization problem ==================
prob = plp.LpProblem(name='Max_Z', sense=plp.LpMaximize)
power_vars = np.array(
    [
        plp.LpVariable(name=f'x({i})', cat=plp.LpInteger, lowBound=1, upBound=5000)
        for i in range(1, SIZE+1)
    ]
)
newX = (power_vars * unit_production_volume)
new_total_production_volume = plp.lpSum(newX)
prob += new_total_production_volume == total_production_volume, 'total_production_volume_constraint'

objective = plp.lpSum(newX * unit_cost_power)
prob.setObjective(objective)
prob.solve()
# Outputs:
"""
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - /opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/apis/../solverdir/cbc/osx/64/cbc /var/folders/t5/5_nvwwz94jq9nfwy6zv8s3_40000gn/T/d58cce82fdee4acdb99f667a30f2a8e7-pulp.mps max timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution /var/folders/t5/5_nvwwz94jq9nfwy6zv8s3_40000gn/T/d58cce82fdee4acdb99f667a30f2a8e7-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 6 COLUMNS
At line 35047 RHS
At line 35049 BOUNDS
At line 52570 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 1 rows, 8760 columns and 8760 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 8.18175e+07 - 0.01 seconds
Cgl0004I processed model has 1 rows, 8760 columns (8760 integer (0 of which binary)) and 8760 elements
Cbc0012I Integer solution of -81817549 found by DiveCoefficient after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.20 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 1 rows 8760 columns, reduced to 1 rows 2 columns
Cbc0012I Integer solution of -81817549 found by DiveCoefficient after 3 iterations and 0 nodes (0.34 seconds)
Cbc0031I 1 added rows had average density of 4
Cbc0013I At root node, 1 cuts changed objective from -81817549 to -81817549 in 4 passes
Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Probing) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 4173 column cuts (4173 active)  in 0.107 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 1 (Gomory) - 3 row cuts average 4.3 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.001 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 2 (Knapsack) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.011 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 3 (Clique) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.001 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 4 (MixedIntegerRounding2) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.001 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 5 (FlowCover) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.001 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective -81817548.79006523, took 3 iterations and 0 nodes (0.34 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 6 variables fixed on reduced cost
Cuts at root node changed objective from -8.18175e+07 to -8.18175e+07
Probing was tried 4 times and created 4173 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.107 seconds)
Gomory was tried 4 times and created 3 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.001 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 4 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.011 seconds)
Clique was tried 4 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.001 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 4 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.001 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 4 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.001 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 1 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
ZeroHalf was tried 1 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                81817548.79006523
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               3
Time (CPU seconds):             0.33
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.35

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.35   (Wallclock seconds):       0.38
"""

# -- Print the First Optimization Problem results ------------------------
print(f'Max production cost: ${objective.value():,.2f}')
print(f'Original production cost: ${total_cost:,}')
print(f'Max/Original production cost ratio: {objective.value()/total_cost:.2f}x ({objective.value()/total_cost:.2%})')
# Prints:
# Max production cost: $81,817,548.79
# Original production cost: $54,587,293.7678924
# Max/Original production cost ratio: 1.50x (149.88%)


# == Define and solve the second optimization problem ===============
prob2 = plp.LpProblem(name='Min_Z', sense=plp.LpMinimize)
power_vars2 = np.array(
    [
        plp.LpVariable(name=f'x({i})', cat=plp.LpInteger, lowBound=1, upBound=5000)
        for i in range(1, SIZE+1)
    ]
)
newX2 = (power_vars2 * unit_production_volume)
new_total_production_volume2 = plp.lpSum(newX2)
prob2 += new_total_production_volume2 == total_production_volume, 'total_production_volume_constraint'

objective2 = plp.lpSum(newX2 * unit_cost_power)
prob2.setObjective(objective2)
prob2.solve()
# Outputs:
"""
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - /opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/apis/../solverdir/cbc/osx/64/cbc /var/folders/t5/5_nvwwz94jq9nfwy6zv8s3_40000gn/T/1b2bfae64e3943a782246a4adeec480b-pulp.mps timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution /var/folders/t5/5_nvwwz94jq9nfwy6zv8s3_40000gn/T/1b2bfae64e3943a782246a4adeec480b-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 6 COLUMNS
At line 35047 RHS
At line 35049 BOUNDS
At line 52570 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 1 rows, 8760 columns and 8760 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 2.71781e+07 - 0.01 seconds
Cgl0004I processed model has 1 rows, 8760 columns (8760 integer (0 of which binary)) and 8760 elements
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 27178139 found by greedy equality after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.18 seconds)
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective 27178138.58848853, took 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.18 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost
Cuts at root node changed objective from 2.71781e+07 to 2.71781e+07
Probing was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Gomory was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Clique was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
ZeroHalf was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                27178138.58848853
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.18
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.19

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.20   (Wallclock seconds):       0.21
"""
# -- Print the Second Optimization Problem results ------------------------
print(f'Min production cost: ${objective2.value():,.2f}')
print(f'Original production cost: ${total_cost:,}')
print(f'Min/Original production cost ratio: {objective2.value()/total_cost:.2f}x ({objective2.value()/total_cost:.2%})')
# Prints:
# Min production cost: $27,178,138.59
# Original production cost: $54,587,293.7678924
# Min/Original production cost ratio: 0.50x (49.79%)
```

> **Note:** Since I'm using random values to generate the data, your end results might vary, If you execute the above code.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the logic of your solution, but it lacks one aspect. How can I define a new array based on actual values on the variable array (values of power_vars)? It's another variable then. In my source code I use these values to build a new array using a look up table (#create Consumption_for_power_array). How can I implement such variable array creation using values of power_vars?

Comment: @Anton Use the following code: `power_values = list(map(lambda value: value.varValue, power_vars))`